# Content based routing in camel

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I was trying to write a program to perform content based routing using apache camel. I wanted to poll a particular folder and seperate the files into different folders based on their file type. I wrote the following code :-

```
 public void configure() throws Exception {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String path = sc.next();
                from("file:"+path+"?noop=true")
                        .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
                        .choice()
                        .when(header("CamelFileNameConsumed").endsWith(".html"))
                        .to("file:HTML files")
                        .when(header("CamelFileNameConsumed").endsWith(".txt"))
                        .to("file:Text Files")
                        .when(header("CamelFileNameConsumed").endsWith(".cpp"))
                        .to("file:Cpp Files")
                        .when(header("CamelFileNameConsumed").endsWith(".xlsx"))
                        .to("file:Excel Files")
                        .when(header("CamelFileNameConsumed").endsWith(".png"))
                        .to("file:Images")
                        .when(header("CamelFileNameConsumed").endsWith(".jpg"))
                        .to("file:Images")
                        .otherwise()
                        .to("file:other")
                        .end()
                        .to("file:all");
            }
```

While I was writing I realized that an image file and video file may have many formats.. I want to avoid writing new line of code for each file type. For eg : I want to include all image file types like jpeg,png etc in one .when() condition. Is there a way to do it because ||(or) dosen't seem to work in this case.  I would be glad if anyone can also suggest any improvements to this code.

Comment: [Predicate](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/predicate.html) should allow you to define `or(a, b)` and stuff like this

Comment: See the dynamic router. You could setup a map of file types to folder destinations and have use that. https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/dynamicRouter-eip.html